# How can I export my contacts from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm tired of Ubuntu One failing to sync with my Evolution installation.  I want to start using funambol, or google, or anything else that works consistently.  I need to know how to export my Ubuntu One contacts to a csv, or other common file type.

Comment: While the other answers have provided information that helps with exporting contacts from Evolution or some other application, I think it would be more appropriate to have an export option for contacts directly from Ubuntu One in ICAL or some other standard format.

Answer (score 1):

So i had the same problem and got around it using evolution to export all contacts to a .vcf file, allthough i had some problems i had to parse that file. instructions can be found here: [How to export contacts from ubuntu one](http://larsemil.se/how-to-export-your-contacts-from-evolution-when-using-ubuntu-one/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Contacts). After copying the contacts back into your local addressbook, follow the instructions [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=142680) (make sure to use the locate command, don't just blindly copy what's written in the post).

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial...
This doesn't work. The plugin doesn't seem to be compatible with newer versions of Thunderbird.

Comment: I thought you're using Evolution!? It works just fine with my own installation (Ubuntu 10.10), I tried it before I posted this. What exactly is the problem?